# Independence Exercise in Rosenthal

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

In Rosenthal's, "[A First Look At Rigorous Probability Theory](http://www.drchristiansalas.org.uk/MathsandPhysics/Measure/AFirstLookAtRigorousProbabilityTheory.pdf)", $\exists$ this exercise:

**Exercise 3.6.19.**

Let $A_1,\ A_2,\ldots$ be independent events. Let $Y$ be a 
random variable which is measurable with respect to $\sigma(A_n, A_{n+1},\ldots)$ for 
each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that there is a real number a such that $P(Y = a) = 1.$

[Hint: Consider $P(Y \leq x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$; what values can it take?]

I have a feeling that this has something to do with intersections?

Must we find x s.t. $P(Y \leq x \cap Y \geq x) = 1$ ?

What does measurable the given $\sigma$ -algebra have to do with this anyway? If $Y$ is measurable there, then $Y^{-1}(B) \in \sigma(A_n, A_{n+1},\ldots),\ \forall B \in \frak{B}$...? Choose $B = (-\infty,x]$?

I dunno. Help please. :(

Comment: Do you know Kolmogorov's zero-one law, or is it to be proved? (In the latter case, [the proof](http://planetmath.org/kolmogorovzeroonelaw) is not long).

Comment: You're essentially looking at Kolmogorov's 0-1 law. Have you heard of this?

Comment: Ah, tail sigma-algebras was not discussed yet so this will not be on the exam. Thanks for the help for the upcoming exams though.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Try to show that there exists $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$P[Y \leq a] = 1 \text{ and } P[Y < a] = 0$$
by Kolmogorov $0$-$1$ law and $\lim_{x \to \infty} P[Y \leq x] = 1$ and $\lim_{x \to -\infty}P[Y \leq x] = 0$.

---

More explicitly, let $F(x) = P[Y \leq x]$ be the distribution function of $Y$, then $F$ is nondecreasing, right-continuous and takes only two values $0$ and $1$, what would happen?